# How to hidden input field in wpc7 form wordpress

Tags: wordpress

```
 [utm_campaign_i]<input type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" value="%s" />[/utm_campaign_i]
```

Output - [utm_campaign_i][utm_campaign_i]

I want to hidden

How to hidden [utm_campaign_i][utm_campaign_i] this